# Offseting lines with same symbology in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, utility-network

I'm working in ArcMap 10 and have been tossed an electrical system map drawn in CAD to recreate in ArcMap. In several sections, different line numbers share the same structures for long stretches. Many times these have the same voltage (which is what they are symbolized on). Is there a way for me to continue symbolizing these lines by voltage while showing 3 separate lines that are not stacked for one section, 2 separate for another, etc?

Comment: Yes .... you can offset the lines without actually editing the locations of the features ...  BUT ... What about addressing this with your symbology choices and legend?  You could build attribution such that you can convey your information with colors, line weights/styles?  I would be hesitant with regard to displaying inaccurate locations of features on such a drawing.  I hope I've understood what you're trying to do.  If not, disregard my suggestion.

Comment: Related: [Cartographic techniques for symbolizing routing data](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27806/cartographic-techniques-for-symbolizing-routing-data)

Comment: Good suggestion blah238

Comment: Dano - I agree with you on displaying inaccurate locations. This is pretty much an overview map just showing "routes" of the lines and which lay on the same paths. I agree symbology weights, styles, etc. are most likely the best way to handle this, but it seems that this is easier for people to view and understand on an overview level. Blah238 - Thanks! This looks pretty spot on to what I'm looking for.

Comment: @MaryBeth - would you consider marking answers as accepted  for some previous questions if it resolved your issues?

Answer (score 2):

If you have ArcEditor or ArcInfo you can use "[Cartograhic Representations](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/What_are_representations/008t00000002000000/)". Representations can have 2 geometries:

- the (original) feature geometry
- a different geometry for displaying the line. so you can offset the lines so that all 3 lines are shown as separate lines side by side.