# Network Analyst resolved route can't display properly on printed map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, network-analyst, overlapping-features

I have looked on the Internet but there are no updated answers. I am using ArcMap 10.2. I am trying to print the route resolved by network analyst but there is no way I can display overlapped generated route when printed.

[image]

This is an example where the encircled section is passed through three times. Please help with how I can show them separately.

Answer (score 1):

There have been some earlier Q&As here and postings on Esri's Mapping Center blog:

- [How to represent overlapping lines in ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37777/how-to-represent-overlapping-lines-in-arcgis-10-1)
- [Cartographic techniques for symbolizing routing data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27806/cartographic-techniques-for-symbolizing-routing-data)
- [display overlapping bus lines](http://mappingcenter.esri.com/index.cfm?fa=ask.answers&q=398)
- [Show overlapping lines](http://mappingcenter.esri.com/index.cfm?fa=ask.answers&q=252)

but they seem mostly to point back to an Esri Mapping Center blog entitled [Create route maps with the ArcGIS schematics extension](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2007/12/12/create-route-maps-with-the-arcgis-schematics-extension/) as being the most practical solution, especially when you start to have more than three lines/routes overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

There's basically no simple solution to this issue. Because the route traverses the same edge more than once, you're going to have overlap. You could add directional arrows to the lines, but then you'll still have overlap just with arrows pointing both directions.

You could do the route as separate legs to each stop and color them differently, but you'll still end up with a line on top of another line and only see the topmost color. Directional arrows in different colors, changing the width of the legs (so the bottom is widest, similar to the dual carriageways in your example image), or several other symbology tweaks could make it possible to see how the overlap is working. Of course, this involves doing three separate routes, or saving the route to a file and breaking the line apart. You could also manually draw lines somewhat parallel to each other to symbolize, but that's even a bit more work.

This issue is usually handled by the use of [Directions](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00470000005w000000), where in text it will list the turns, directions, and distances to travel in the correct order for the route. Having the stops symbolized with numbers as shown is also usually sufficient to determine the route, at least in smaller solutions such as this with minimal stops and backtracking.

Comment: Yes Chris, you are correct, however, I am working with 1000+ complicated street routes, which are supposed to serve as directions for laymen, and that overlapping technique would only make it complicated. I have seen posts from pre-2008 and am still surprised esri havent handled the issue inside arcmap.

Comment: there are couple of ways  i believe it can be done i am not just sure about the scripting or actual arcmap tools that'll be used. 1) Simply passes between two points are defined as passes, user would be setting the distance between  two points. once the passes any segment becomes 2 or 3 offset is carried out, whilst directional arrows would be used on top of the, as usual, 2) Secodnly, if there's any way we can make route chnage its thickness and color (as gradient) as a function of the distance travelled.

Comment: 3) third solution can be exporting this route as a shape file and manipulate to to desired outcome in any opensource gis suite that can get our desired results 4)Any thrid party extensions that know there way around .  .

Comment: so anybody who knows please help.