# Offsetting Overlapping Routes in Network Analyst

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, route

[image: Current Route Lines]

I've seen some questions tackle this issue, but havent myself found a working solution. Using ArcMap 10.2.2 Advanced with Network Analyst.

I use the Vehicle Routing Problem to route a couple delivery vehicles around, some resultant routes overlap.

Is there anyway to show all the routes at once? From my picture for instance, the intersection of the yellow/red/green lines, I would like to see all 3 travelling down Valley Blvd, instead of the highest ranked route.

Comment: Can you describe what is or isn't working for you from any of the solutions given at those other questions to distinguish this as not a duplicate of them? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/114580/network-analyst-resolved-route-cant-display-properly-on-printed-map and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27806/cartographic-techniques-for-symbolizing-routing-data come to mind as examples you may be referring to.

Comment: The duplicates are a little messy on this but I agree with @ChrisW that yours appears to be a duplicate.  If you decide to try and edit to separate your requirements from those of the current duplicate be sure to also review http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37777/how-to-represent-overlapping-lines-in-arcgis-for-desktop